# Is there a way to effectively GRANT on either TRUNCATE or DROP TABLE in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, permissions

I recently tried this in MySQL 5.5.x:

```
GRANT
    SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, TRUNCATE ON crawler.*
    TO 'my_user'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

This results in an error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TRUNCATE ON crawler.*
>   TO 'my_user'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION' at line 2

This used to work before I added `TRUNCATE`, so after a bit of research I find that this is not supported in MySQL.

The reason for this is that `TRUNCATE` is classified as a DDL operation, and so it doesn't use `DELETE` internally, it uses `DROP`. Alright, so I'd like to restrict this user to dropping tables (in the event of a security breach, at least a malicious user would have to determine the names of tables and drop them individually).

However, it turns out I would need to grant this user the `DROP` privilege, which allows the user to drop whole databases too. Given that there is not [a grant for individual tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html), is there another way to do this? I suppose I could hand this off to another process with a different user, but it feels a bit cumbersome for such a small issue.

For the time being, I'll stick with `DELETE`, even though it is rather slow! (On my laptop it takes ~55 sec to delete 1.6M small rows, and a fraction of a second to truncate the same). However, I am all ears if there is a faster and secure alternative.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To grant DROP privilege on a specific table in a specific database to a specific user in MySQL, you can use a GRANT statement like this. (This assumes that table `fi` exists in database `fee`, and this is the table you want to allow the user `'fo'@'%'` to be able to TRUNCATE):

```
  GRANT DROP ON TABLE fee.fi TO 'fo'@'%'
```

To see that the user has privilege to truncate that specific table:

```
  SHOW GRANTS FOR 'fo'@'%' ;
```

And connect as user `'fo'@'%'` to test:

```
  TRUNCATE TABLE fee.fi ;
```

(Obviously, the user also has the privilege to DROP that same table. But that's just the way it is in MySQL.)

---

As an alternative, to allow the user to perform *only* the TRUNCATE operation on that specific table, without granting the user `DROP` privilege on the table...

create a stored procedure that performs a `TRUNCATE fee.fi;` (That will probably need to be executed dynamically since it's DDL.) The procedure will need to be created with `DEFINER` privileges, and created by a user that has the required privileges.

Then you can grant execute on the procedure to the user:

```
  GRANT EXECUTE ON fee.truncate_table_fee_fi TO 'fo'@'%';
```

Then user `'fo'@'%'` can

```
  CALL fee.truncate_table_fee_fi
```

Comment: Ah great, I didn't think individual tables could be affected with a `GRANT DROP` - will give this a go! Thank you. (I think I've gotten so used to `ON fee.*` that I've forgotten the `*` can be swapped with individual table names).

Comment: Out of interest: in order to be able to `DROP DATABASE`, does a user simply need to have permissions to drop all tables i.e. a star in the `GRANT` for `DROP`?

Comment: @halfer:  I only drop databases as a privileged user (e.g. `root`) that has `Drop_priv=Y` in the `mysql.user` table. I think that's equivalent to **`on *.*`** in the GRANT/REVOKE statements. I don't think **`grant drop on fee.*`**  would give user privilege to **`drop database fee`**, but I've never tried/tested it. (Obviously, it would give the user privilege to empty out the database, dropping all objects in the database.)

Comment: Alright, thanks. I've tried dropping the database when the user only has permission to drop a single table, and as expected, this is denied - which is what I am after.