# MySQL grants to create a stored procedure on performance_schema.*?

Tags: mysql

I understand why this is so locked down. If I were MySQL, I wouldn't want folks to (easily) shoot themselves in the foot on business critical/internal-use databases either. Nevertheless, it should support legitimate use cases.

Suppose I had a stored procedure:

```sql
delimiter //
CREATE DEFINER=CURRENT_USER() PROCEDURE performance_schema.sp_flush_hosts()
BEGIN
  -- requires DROP privileges
  TRUNCATE TABLE performance_schema.host_cache;
END
//
delimiter ;
```

for a user called `root` with `ALL` permissions on *most* databases.
In practice, MySQL seems to [explicitly forbid this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-perfschema-excerpt/8.0/en/performance-schema-table-characteristics.html) for `performance_schema`:

> Because only a limited set of privileges apply to Performance Schema tables, attempts to use GRANT ALL as shorthand for granting privileges at the database or table leval fail with an error:

Fine. So let's grant some specific permissions:

```sql
mysql> GRANT CREATE ROUTINE on perforamnce_schema.host_cache to 'root'@'%';
ERROR 1144 (42000): Illegal GRANT/REVOKE command; please consult the manual to see which privileges can be used
```

In the same document (above), only: SELECT, UPDATE, DROP are singled out, but it does not say if those are the only available permissions. How would I grant permissions to create this routine? Is that even possible? Thanks.

Inspiration taken from this SO answer: [Is there a way to effectively GRANT on either TRUNCATE or DROP TABLE in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36227470/is-there-a-way-to-effectively-grant-on-either-truncate-or-drop-table-in-mysql#answer-36227834)

Comment: Why don't you use flush hosts statement instead? What's the point of creating this stored procedure instead?

Comment: BTW, you are trying to grant create routine privilege to a table, hence the error message. Create routine privilege can only be granted on global or database level.

Comment: `flush hosts` is deprecated as of 8.0.23 (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flush.html#flush-hosts), and we're writing this process to be forward-compatible by following the docs. The point is that I don't want an arbitrary user to have `DROP` privileges on this DB/table, which is what's required in new versions. Hence, create a SP, delegate `EXECUTE` to arbitrary users, profit?

Thanks for pointing out that I was trying my grant on the table, but I'm still getting 'access denied' when I attempt to create a procedure on the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

- Put your SP in your database.  Or perhaps a generic database of "utilities".
- Be "root" when you `CREATE` the SP, and declare it with `SQL SECURITY DEFINER`  See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-objects-security.html#stored-objects-security-sql-security  This provides a way to elevate the permissions just for the running of the SP.  Normally, one would use `SQL SECURITY INVOKER` -- to use the permissions of the person `CALLing` the SP.